# Virtual host not accessible in intranet

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, virtualhost

Could it be possible to create a virtual host using tomcat and apache which can be accessible in an intranet ??

I am a newbie in using jsp and tomcat but I have been able to create a virtual host, but it is not accessible in the intranet. What do I have to do to make it accessible on the intranet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible to create a virtual host using tomcat and apache. But in order to make it accessible in the local intranet you need to add an entry of your ip address to the /etc/hosts file of the memeber machines of the intranet unless they will not be able to recognize the virtual host you have created.

Which is not feasible at all because the /etc/hosts file is managed by the root itself and it is refreshed on every restart by root. You can add a sticky bit to the file but it is like an intrusion to the machine/company policies which should not be done.

:)